# Is my solution ok in this test

Tags: past-tense

At the end of the party, no one 
 was happier than Sarah and Tim as they 
 **found** each other after 2 years.

I answered **"had found"** but I think my solution is good if I want to emphasize the finding was the cause of their happines, furthermore they found then they were happy

englishexercises.org/makeagame/viewgame.asp?id=414

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Had found" is correct and a reasonable solution to this question. The implied time is "past" and "had found" is a past tense. It suggests that Tim and Sarah found each other during the party, and not at the end of the party.